# Android - Interface callBack throws null pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, interface, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I've a asyntask for all my activities/fragments etc, but now i'am implementing an interface for each activity but my interface callBack is always null and i can't figure out why. The activity each call the asyncTask implements the interface.

**My class who implements the interface and call's the asyncTask**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MainActivityAsyncInterface, OnClickListener, UserPictureDialogInterface {

private DrawerLayout            moodydrawerLayout;

private HashMap<String, String> organizedCourses    = new HashMap<String, String>();

// ManSession Manager Class
ManSession                      session;

private long                    startTime;
private long                    endTime;
private ModDevice               md;

private float                   screenX;

private float                   screenY;

private int                     shotType            = ShowcaseView.TYPE_ONE_SHOT;

private MoodleUser              currentUser;

private String                  url;

private String                  token;

private String                  userId;

private static long             backPressed;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // The following line triggers the initialization of ACRA
.......

    session = new ManSession(getApplicationContext());
    url = session.getValues(ModConstants.KEY_URL, null);
    token = session.getValues(ModConstants.KEY_TOKEN, null);
    userId = session.getValues(ModConstants.KEY_ID, null);

    new DataAsyncTask(this,).execute(url, token, EXAMPLE.CORE_USER_GET_USERS_BY_ID, userId, MainActivity.class.getSimpleName());

    populateLeft();
    populateRight();
    receiveNotification();
    initDemoOverlay();
    drawerLayoutListener();
    warningMessage(checkConnection(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG, null, getString(R.string.no_internet));

    ChangeLogListView sad = new ChangeLogListView(getApplicationContext());

}
```

**AsyncTask**

```
public class DataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Object> {
Object                              jObj    = null;
public MainActivityAsyncInterface   mainActivityInterface;
private ProgressDialog              dialog;
private CountDownTimer              cvt     = createCountDownTimer();
private Context                     context;
private MoodleServices              webService;
private String                      parentActivity;
private String                      fillTheSpace;

public DataAsyncTask(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    cvt.start();
}

@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
    String urlString = (String) params[0];
    String token = (String) params[1];
    webService = (MoodleServices) params[2];
    Object webServiceParams = params[3];
    parentActivity = (String) params[4];

        case EXAMPLE:
            InputStream inputStream = new URL(urlString).openStream();
            Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, null);
            inputStream.close();
            return drawable;

        default:
            return null;

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * <p>
 * Method that parses a supposed id list object
 * </p>
 *
 * @param Object
 *            ids - The object to be parsed to Long[].
 * @return resultList - The ids List
 */
private Long[] parseIds(Object ids) {

    Long[] resultList = null;

    try {
        resultList = (Long[]) ids;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        resultList = new Long[1];

        resultList[0] = (Long) ids;
    }

    return resultList;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object obj) {
    cvt.cancel();

    if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing())   
        dialog.dismiss();

    switch (webService) {
    case EXAMPLE:
        if (parentActivity.equalsIgnoreCase(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName()))
            mainActivityInterface.userAsyncTaskResult(obj); \\This the line 173 and the obj != null and mainActivityInterface is null

        if (parentActivity.equalsIgnoreCase(UserDetailsActivity.class.getSimpleName()))
            fillTheSpace = "TODO - Interface for each parent class";

        if (parentActivity.equalsIgnoreCase(FragTopicsPreview.class.getSimpleName()))
            fillTheSpace = "TODO - Interface for each parent class";

        if (parentActivity.equalsIgnoreCase(FragTopics.class.getSimpleName()))
            fillTheSpace = "TODO - Interface for each parent class";
        break;

    case EXAMPLE2:
        if (parentActivity.equalsIgnoreCase(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName()))
            mainActivityInterface.userAsyncTaskResult(obj);

        if (parentActivity.equalsIgnoreCase(UserDetailsActivity.class.getSimpleName()))
            fillTheSpace = "TODO - Interface for each parent class";

        if (parentActivity.equalsIgnoreCase(FragTopicsPreview.class.getSimpleName()))
            fillTheSpace = "TODO - Interface for each parent class";

        if (parentActivity.equalsIgnoreCase(FragTopics.class.getSimpleName()))
            fillTheSpace = "TODO - Interface for each parent class";
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}

private CountDownTimer createCountDownTimer() {
    return new CountDownTimer(250, 10) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            dialog.show();
        }
    };
}
```

Logcat:

```
04-27 11:54:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1428): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-27 11:54:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1428): Process: com.firetrap.moody, PID: 1428
04-27 11:54:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1428): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-27 11:54:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at connections.DataAsyncTask.onPostExecute(DataAsyncTask.java:173)
04-27 11:54:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
04-27 11:54:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access(AsyncTask.java:177)
04-27 11:54:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
04-27 11:54:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-27 11:54:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-27 11:54:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-27 11:54:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-27 11:54:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-27 11:54:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-27 11:54:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-27 11:54:11.520: E/AndroidRuntime(1428):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

From my experience the interface doesn't should send a nullPointer Exception with my code and an interface doesn't need to be initialized but at this point i put all options on the table.

Comment: Which line is onPostExecute(DataAsyncTask.java:173)?

Comment: I've a comment on the code flagging the line:  mainActivityInterface.userAsyncTaskResult(obj); \\This the line 173 and the obj != null and mainActivityInterface is null

Comment: you are not initializing mainActivityInterface, if you are then where?

Comment: You never set `mainActivityInterface` to a value so it is null.

Comment: A value?! mainActivityInterface it's a interface, are you suggesting to initializing an interface?! like mainActivityInterface = toSomething?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cause because you never pass the listener into your task.

You only send your context in the constrctuor but it should look like this:

```
public DataAsyncTask(Context context , MainActivityAsyncInterface mainActivityInterface) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mainActivityInterface = mainActivityInterface;
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
}
```

In your activity add this to where you start your Task.

```
  YourAcivity.this.
```

Update:
Answer to your question,

You can create BaseActivity which will extends Activity and implement your listener.
then, all your activities will have to override the listener function.

Comment: I've see this possibilitie but the problem is i will have more than 6 interface each interface for each activity, so the only solution is to have 6 constructors, has the interface have a generic type?

Comment: You must understand first, that you cannot use the listener until you init it somewhere.

Comment: @firetrap You seem to use only `userAsyncTaskResult` method from your interface. It should be the interface that defines that method.

Comment: You can create  BaseActivity which extends Activity and implement your listener, and then all your activities will extends this class.

Comment: So i've added to the constructor, but what doesn't seems right its the activity who call's the asyncTask already have the interface implemented so from what i know it's allready init from the activity, i will update my code for better understanding

Comment: Doesn't matter, the async task class dont have access to your activity unless to send your listener which is YourAcivity.this.

Answer (score 1):

If `MainActivityAsyncInterface` is an interface that your activity implements, you need to pass it to your async task. Currently `mainActivityInterface` is never initialised and is always null so you get your exception.

You can pass a reference in your constructor

```
public DataAsyncTask(Context context, MainActivityAsyncInterface mainActivityInterface) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mainActivityInterface = mainActivityInterface;
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
}
```